# Render Radio Button Django

Tags: django-forms

I Have this Form

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
boolfield = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=bool,
               choices=((False, 'No'), (True, 'Yes')),
               widget=forms.RadioSelect
            )

class Meta:
     model = MyModel
```

How can I show the buttons without LI an UL tags ? (I want to show them together horizontally), and how to set False selected by default? ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `initial` property on the field should select False.

You can also [custom render](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) the field to display them how you want. You could also define a new widget, but I don't have a link handy for that.